# jQuery .change and .click function simultaneously

Tags: jquery, function, drop-down-menu

can someone take a look at this please

http://jsfiddle.net/bloodygeese/ecscY/56/

it looks like I have got the 2 separate functions working but I need to get them to both work at the same time? So clicking on image1.image2,image3,image4 will change the drop down, but I also need to display the value of the drop down at the same time,

It seems I can only do this separately?

It would also be great if I could get the "label:"to display the 1st option as default.
And i am going to have 16(maybe more) options in the drop down, is there any way the code can be simplified? rather than a function for each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
$('#one, #two, #three, #four').click(function() {
    $('#dropdown').val($(this).attr('id'));
    $('#dropdown').trigger('change')
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ecscY/57/

Comment: even better! how would i get the Label:# to show "one" by default?

Answer (score 0):

Call `.change()` after calling `.val()`. See below,

```
$('#dropdown').val($(this).attr('id')).change();
```